# Error value NaN when passing multiple params with node.js

Tags: node.js

Console.log In Back end prints

req.params.region :  NaN  req.params.category : Plumbing

but the front end is clearly passing the value as Frontend console logs:
this is criteria: {"region":"Queensland","category":"Plumbing"}

so why am i getting a Value of NaN (for region) when Plumbing is being passed just fine?

FRONTEND

```
export const getAllFilteredJobPosts = (criteria) => dispatch => {

      console.log("this is criteria: " + JSON.stringify(criteria))

        dispatch({ type: LOADING_DATA })
        axios.get(`https://australia-southeast1-workservices-e4506.cloudfunctions.net/api/FilteredJobPosts/${criteria.region}/${criteria.category}`)

        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_ALL_JOB_POSTS,
                payload: res.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_ALL_JOB_POSTS,
                payload: []
            })
        })
    }
```

BACKEND

```
app.get('/FilteredJobPosts/:region/:category',getSearchFilteredJobPosts );


exports.getSearchFilteredJobPosts = (req, res) => {

  console.log("req.params.region : ",  + req.params.region, " req.params.category : "  + req.params.category)

db.collection('JobPosts').doc(`${req.params.region}`).collection(`${req.params.category}`).orderBy('timestamp','desc').get()
    .then(data => {
        let jobPosts = [];
        data.forEach(doc => {
            jobPosts.push({
                jobId: doc.id,
                ...doc.data()
            });
        });
    return res.json(jobPosts);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
console.log("req.params.region : ",  + req.params.region, " req.params.category : "  + req.params.category)
```

after the first string you have a comma followed by a + sign. This means the thing after it is not added to the string, but it is the second argument to console.log. That second argument starts with a + so it gets interpreted as a number - which it is not.

So remove the comma after the first string and it should work.

Comment: I'm an idiot , guessing this will work now thanks

Comment: Yes is worked, is their an error package for Node.js that highlights those kind of silly errors?

Comment: @benpalmer I guess the problem with that is, the package would have to know your intentions. If `req.params.region` was *supposed* to be a number, this was a useful error message. My best advice would be to learn the use of debuggers - they show you what’s in a variable and how it gets used. It takes a while, but the time is paid back sooner than you think.